# How do I make fieldsets sortable by wrapping them in list items using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, word-wrap

I have a group of fieldset elements within a form. I need to make them sortable. Most of the plug-ins are based on the idea of a sorting a list - so I'm trying to turn a set of

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" value="1" id="item_0_sort_1" name="item[0][sort]">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" value="1" id="item_0_sort_2" name="item[0][sort]">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" value="1" id="item_0_sort_3" name="item[0][sort]">
</fieldset>
```

into

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <fieldset>
      <input type = "text" value="1" id="item_0_sort_1" name="item[0][sort]">
    </fieldset>
  </li>
  <li>
    <fieldset>
      <input type = "text" value="2" id="item_0_sort_2" name="item[0][sort]">
    </fieldset>
  </li>
  <li>
    <fieldset>
      <input type = "text" value="3" id="item_0_sort_3" name="item[0][sort]">
    </fieldset>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(And no, this I can't change the HTML :-( )

I can wrap the fieldsets no problem,

```
$('form').children('fieldset').wrap('<li>');
```

but can't seem to see how to either move the fieldset elements into a `<ul>`? Right now I'm planning on using jquery.dragsort to move the items around, and have jQuery renumber the `input.val()`s accordingly - any suggestions for the callback would be greatly appreciated too.

Or am I going about it the right way? if there's a way to sort the fieldsets directly, that would be better I suspect.

Comment: can you tell me which plugin you are using for sortable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wrapAll`:

```
$('form li').wrapAll("<ul/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vVAzu/).

Here's the markup:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" value="1" id="item_0_sort_1" name="item[0][sort]">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" value="1" id="item_0_sort_2" name="item[0][sort]">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" value="1" id="item_0_sort_3" name="item[0][sort]">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('form >*').wrap('<li>');
$('form li').wrapAll('<ul>');
```

Comment: ... but I like the jsFiddle site! Thanks roXon

Comment: @ Dycey --> Thanks! I was not trying to copy Edgard's answer, just to make things work! I'm glad YOU make it work!! +1 to Edgar